# Can't install a cuda-accelerated library (GPU-LIBSVM)

Tags: linux, cuda, makefile, libsvm

I'm trying to install the cuda-accelerated library found on this website : http://mklab.iti.gr/project/GPU-LIBSVM

I downloaded the linux makefile and executable and tried to follow the readme file :

> Instructions to compile Linux GPU-Accelerated LIBSVM
>
> 1. Install the NVIDIA drivers, CUDA toolkit and GPU Computing SDK code samples. You can find them in:
>
> http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_downloads.html (January
>   2011)
>
> You may need some additional packets to be installed in order to
>   complete the installations above.  Please refer to the web for more
>   details.
>
> 1. Copy this folder to "/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/src"
> 2. Use the Makefile found in "/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C"
> 3. Find the "svm-train-gpu" executable in /NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/bin/linux/release

But i could not find the "NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK" folder, even after upgrading cuda to 5.5 (wich should contain the SDK). It seems that this instructions are outdated. So I copied the folder into "opt/cuda/src/" and used this makefile :

```
EXECUTABLE  := svm-train-gpu
CUFILES     :=
CU_DEPS     :=
CCFILES      := svm-train.c svm.cpp 
CUDACCFLAGS     := -po maxrregcount=16
USECUBLAS       := 1
include ../../common/common.mk
```

It first told me it could not find "common.mk", so I found in my disk an other common.mk file from an other CUDA project implementation called "common-gcc-cuda-4.0.mk" wich is described in the header as a "Common build script for CUDA source projects for Linux and Mac platforms" and tried again.

Now I have this error :

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `makedirectories', needed by `bin/linux/release/svm-train-gpu'.  Stop.
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the authors of the library. I don't see how this is a CUDA programming question and I don't understand what you expect an answer would contain.

Comment: Maybe someone had the same problem and found a way to install it. I agree it's not a CUDA programming question, but the library is using it so I tought I could use the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the library is expecting an old version of CUDA.    The structure of the sample codes (GPU_Computing_SDK) changed substantially after CUDA 4.2

Try starting over with an older version of CUDA which you can find [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive).   I would recommend choosing a cuda version from 3.2 to 4.2, and if you install that completely (driver, toolkit and SDK) you will find the folders and makefiles being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

The version you were trying was created with the CUDA SDK 3.0. As Robert pointed out the structure of sample codes and makefiles changed substantially after CUDA 4.2.

A new version (1.2) is online on the mklab website http://mklab.iti.gr/project/GPU-LIBSVM
which supports the latest LIBSVM v3.17 and CUDA SDK v5.5.

Also you can see a detailed changelog here: https://github.com/MKLab-ITI/CUDA/releases